# java lang outofmemory error while using Animation in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have two buttons, one is used to start **`animation`** and other is used to stop animation. On one device, app is working fine, but on another device it crashes saying **`java.lang.outofmemory`** exception in my **`LogCat`**. Here is my xml for animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/one"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/two"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/three"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/four"
        android:duration="200"/>

</animation-list>
```

And here is my activity :

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageAnimation);
    on_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.on);
    off_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.off);
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_list);
    frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();

    on_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });

    off_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            frameAnimation.stop();
        }
    });
}
```

M actually trying to make a splash screen, and its my initial attempt.

Comment: you are getting out of memory because of the images and there size...are you using large imgaes..on small memory devices

Comment: That could be an issue , let me see

Comment: Thnx , it worked on other device, but not on AVD. let me see in my logcat for something to tell u more.

Comment: sure check in your logcat

Comment: Thnx alot @MeenalSharma, its working on AVD now, i was tracking my old LogCat.